# R - filling a column with other columns data

Tags: r

I have the following tibble. First three rows (A,B,C) have number of hours. FINAL is the column I want to change. I have already data-wrangling column A and put it into FINAL, but now I need to use the other two columns, B and C. Column FINAL is supposed to have valid hours, which is cnB data if A is “.” or "NA". If B has also “.” then C data. If C has also “.” then I leave “.” . How can I do this? Thanks

```
df
# A tibble: 22 x 4
   A         B        C        FINAL   
   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
 1 .         .        .        .       
 2 15023:1   .        .        15023:1 
 3 0         .        0        0       
 4 18308:28  .        .        18308:28
 5 14,812.61 .        .        14812.61
 6 17717:36  17717:36 17717:36 17717:36
 7 .         21095:1  .        .       
 8 .         .        12912:33 .       
 9 9849      9849     9849     9849    
10 16548.00  .        .        16548.00
```

Comment: For row 7 and 8, there is data in B or C. Based on the example, FINAL is just the 'A' column.  Is there any typos

Comment: In my example FINAL is not finalized, that's why the question. For row 7 and 8, FINAL should have 21095:1 and 12912:33 respectively.

Comment: Can you please check the solutoin below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use `apply` and select the first value which is not `'.'` or `NA` in each row.

```
df$Final <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x != '.' & !is.na(x)][1])
df

#           A        B        C     Final
#1          .        .        .      <NA>
#2    15023:1        .        .   15023:1
#3          0        .        0         0
#4   18308:28        .        .  18308:28
#5  14,812.61        .        . 14,812.61
#6   17717:36 17717:36 17717:36  17717:36
#7          .  21095:1        .   21095:1
#8          .        . 12912:33  12912:33
#9       9849     9849     9849      9849
#10  16548.00        .        .  16548.00
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Although can't follow much this part   x[x != '.' & !is.na(x)][1]

Comment: that is to remove `'.'` and `NA` values from the data and then selecting the 1st value.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the `.` to `NA` and then use `coalesce` to return a single column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), na_if, '.')) %>%
    transmute(FINAL = coalesce(!!! .)) %>%
    bind_cols(df1, .)
```

-output

```
#           A        B        C     FINAL
#1          .        .        .      <NA>
#2    15023:1        .        .   15023:1
#3          0        .        0         0
#4   18308:28        .        .  18308:28
#5  14,812.61        .        . 14,812.61
#6   17717:36 17717:36 17717:36  17717:36
#7          .  21095:1        .   21095:1
#8          .        . 12912:33  12912:33
#9       9849     9849     9849      9849
#10  16548.00        .        .  16548.00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(".", "15023:1", "0", "18308:28", "14,812.61", 
"17717:36", ".", ".", "9849", "16548.00"), B = c(".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", "17717:36", "21095:1", ".", "9849", "."), C = c(".", 
".", "0", ".", ".", "17717:36", ".", "12912:33", "9849", ".")),
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I cannot find "across" function, and have dplyr, tidyverse and tidyr, so could not check it out. However below solution is cleaner, one line only

Comment: @Stack2020 you can update the `dplyr` to 1.0.0 `across` is from that version